# Creating SQL records schema with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core, database-schema

Due to the [SQLite limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations) in migrations, I decided not to use the migration system for now and simply drop, create and fill the tables on each `DbContext` model change.

In order to do that (besides a database backup), I have to perform the following steps:

- Dump current records sql schema,
- Call the `database.EnsureDeleted()` to completely remove the database.
- Call the `database.EnsureCreated()` to create a new database with up-to-date model properties,
- Execute the sql schema to fill the tables

**Hence my question**:

Is it possible to dump the table records schema with EF Core, that will generate `INSERT` queries for us? Or at least move the records from old database to new one?

So far I have only found the `database.GenerateCreateScript()`, but that works only for the tables, indexes and stuff like that, which is basically `EnsureCreated()` sql equivalent.

**Note**: I know I can use sql code in migrations script, but it's really a pain to maintain the table removal, dropping the keys and indexes and create them afterwards. It takes a lot of time, especially when I make changes to the model frequently.